# How we send my data from controller to view and how we detect an error in my function

Tags: php, codeigniter

How we send my data from controller to view and how we detect an error in my function.

```
public function ratings() { 

    $results['value']= $this->Home_registeration->get_ratings($_POST);

    $this->load->view ('display_search_result', $results); 

    Echo "";

    print_R ($results)
}
```

Comment: You can access your data in view like $value.

Answer (score 0):

I have provide a sample code,how to send data from controller to views:
You have to write the following code in controller function

```
$data['title']='ABC';
$data['page']='home';
$this->load->view('home',$data);
```

Now write the following code in home view file:

```
echo "The title is => ".$title;  //The title is => ABC
echo "The page is => ".$page;    //The page is => home
```

In Your case just open the view file namely (display_search_result.php) and write:

```
print_r($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use `$_POST` in codeigniter, use `$this->input->post()` library instead. You can post data to views by passing the second argument in view and looping through array values, or by using class vars:

```
<?php
$data = [
    "id" => 234,
    "name" => "John Smith",
    "status" => 2
];

$this->data->id = 234;
$this->data->name = "John Smith";
$this->data->status = 2;

?>
```

(a) Then call your view :

```
<?php

    $this->load->view('viewname', $data);

?>
```

(b) OR :

```
<?php

    $this->load->view('viewname');

?>
```

(a) Then in your view file:

```
<p><?= $id ?></p>
<p><?= $name ?></p>
<p><?= $status ?></p>
```

(b) OR, if you are using `$this->data->id` etc.

```
<p><?= $this->data->id ?></p>
<p><?= $this->data->name ?></p>
<p><?= $this->data->status ?></p>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all requirement and all possibility failure before call your function to be proccess.

example:

```
public function ratings() { 
    $parameter = $this->input->post(null, TRUE); // null to get all index and TRUE to xss clean
    $results = array();
    if (empty($parameter))
    {
        $results['value'] = "Please input your parameter first";
    }
    else
    {
        // Asume parameter exist and safe enough to be proccess
        $results['value']= $this->Home_registeration->get_ratings($parameter);
        // you can also check result from get_ratings function
        // asume you will set rating 0 on empty return value from function
        if (empty($results['value'])) $results['value'] = 0;
    }


    $this->load->view ('display_search_result', $results); 

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($results);        
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

Comment: See below the line, in $results I am getting my result (like 2.56554 using Ajax). Now I want to send this value to view the file. But whenever I try to display the result. That gives me an error. $results ['value'] = $this->Home_registeration->get_ratings ($_POST); How can I display values in view file?

Comment: $results['value'] will not exist since error was occured in $this->Home_registration->get_ratings($_POST); what is error you get? please call this url directly (not ajax) to debug the problem

Comment: before pass $_POST to function. you need to check the requirement. maybe $_POST is empty. see at my code. im pass $parameter to the function. where $parameter already being check before call the function

Comment: can you put your view code. near line number 250 on 'display_search_result.php'? it cause by function r wich is undefine on your view

Comment: am not defined r in my function